# How to upgrade Gitlab 7 to 8 with old backup

Tags: git, bash, gitlab, gitlab-7, gitlab-8

I was using Gitlab 7.10.4. I created a backup using the following command :

```
# I have installed GitLab with the Omnibus package
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create
```

Then I tried to upgrade to the lastest Gitlab version (eg. [8.3.4](https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce)) using :

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install gitlab-ce
```

For an unknow reason, this has failed. So I had to install a fresh install of Gitlab, but I don't understand why my old backup can't be installed on the new version of Gitlab which generates a version mismatch error.

How to keep my **old data backup** and **upgrade** to the lastest version of gitlab ?

Comment: Restoring to a newer version won't work, afaik, but the aptitude update should work. It's the approach that worked for me recently. I think your best bet is to dig into why that failed.

Comment: @DonBranson Thanks. So, in your mind, I should reinstall the old version and use my backup ?

Comment: AFAIK backups can be only restored for the version they created with. When it is done, you should upgrade to 8.0 before upgrading further in the 8.x line as it is advised on the 8.1/8.2/8.3 announcement blog post.

Comment: @Zl3n, yes that's what I'd do.

Comment: lots of reasons it could have failed (i.e. migration order, CI inclusion) need more info from logs or gitlab:check to decide. follow @qcz recommendation upgrade to 8.0 for major release stuff before going further.

Comment: @JoseTorres, Thank for your answer. Since this morning, I've reinstalled the old version and now, I can use my backup. But I'm a little disappointed that it is very difficult to move to a newer version without being able to retain its data. At least, easily ...

Comment: I agree, the process you used usually works well and best with 8.x. If you'd like to debug the error I'd be glad to help out on a new thread for that.

Comment: **Answer : https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/tree/master/doc/update**

Answer (score 0):

I've upgraded `Gitlab` 7.10.4 to 8.5.0 using :

```
$ curl -sS https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/script.deb.sh | sudo bash

$ sudo apt-get install gitlab-ce

$ sudo gitlab-ctl restart
```

Comment: But have you restore your backup ?